# Having issues with SharePoint Designer 2013 Announcement WebPart formatting

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-designer

I'm currently using SharePoint Designer 2013 to build an intranet site... I've created an Announcements WebPart to insert on the front page, however I'm having a great deal of difficulty formatting it.

I've attached an image of what it looks like currently.

Does anyone know how to stop the weird image from appearing before the name of the poster? Also if anyone knows how to format the title of each post I would be greatly appreciative.

ps. any other tips in regards to this, or Designer in general would be fantastic

Image showing what my site currently looks like - it displays a random image with lots of colours before the creator's name

[image]

Comment: check from F12 developer window...it looks like image sprite ...

Comment: Okay I'm pretty sure it's the image sprite for Yammer availability but I'm not sure how to fix it? Do you have any idea how I could do this??? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have added your own css that may causing problem .... If not hide it with your own css <style> .class-name{ display : none} </style> ... add css markup to your page